# How to signal to other node that no more work is available from the master node

Tags: c++, mpi

I'd like to request for some help to finish work load distribution in the mpi implementation.

The idea is that node 0 will have a list of file names ("list_file"). When other nodes are free they will send request for a file to node 0 and node 0 will send back the file name.

Once there is no more file to send node 0 finishes its work. However, how do I signal to the reader threads in other nodes that node 0 has no more file and they should stop waiting for node 0 to send  a new file over.

```
// pid 0 will collect all input text file names and distribute them to other nodes
if (pid == 0)
{
    vector<char*> list_file;                    // a vector to hold the input text file names to be processed

    GetInputFile(argv, list_file);              // argv[1] is a text file that contains the input text files to be processed, all the text file names will be added to list_file
    num_file_remaining = list_file.size();      // number of file remained in the queue to be processed

    MPI_Status requeststats;            // for MPI_recv

    // listen to request for file from other nodes as long as there is file left in list_file
    while (num_file_remaining != 0)
    {
        MPI_recv(NULL, 0, MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &requeststats);       // listen to request for file
        MPI_send(list_file.back(), 5 * MAX_WORD_LENGTH, MPI_CHAR, requeststats.MPI_SOURCE, requeststats.MPI_SOURCE, MPI_COMM_WORLD);            // send the file to respective node
        list_file.pop_back();       // remove the file that was just sent
        num_file_remaining -= 1;    // reduce the number of file remained in the queue
    }
}


// other nodes will request work from pid 0
if (pid != 0)
{
    char* file_name;

    while (num_file_remaining != 0)
    {
        MPI_send(NULL, 0, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);           // send the request for a file to node 0
        MPI_recv(file_name, 5 * MAX_WORD_LENGTH, MPI_CHAR, 0, pid, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);      // receive the file from node 0
        cout << "pid: " << pid << " - " << file_name << endl;       // process the file
        // HOW TO EXIT THE LOOP WHEN NO MORE FILE TO RECEIVE FROM NODE 0
    }
}
```

Comment: have the master send an empty string when a slave request some new work and there is no more file to process. master can exit once *all* slaves have been sent the empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Have an active `MPI_Irecv` call:

```
// set this tag to whatever you want and don’t use it for anything else
constexpr int AM_I_FINISHED_TAG = 1376;
MPI_Request am_I_finished = MPI_Irecv(nullptr, 0, MPI_INT, 0, AM_I_FINISHED_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
```

Whenever you finish processing a file on the child node, use MPI_Test to check if that request is complete. When the main node has no more work for a child node, have it send data to all child nodes using the AM_I_FINISHED_TAG.

Comment: There is a race condition here, not to mention this is a bit convoluted IMHO

Comment: How is there a race condition?

Comment: If you `MPI_Test()` when there is no more files to process and before the `AM_I_FINISHED_TAG` message arrives.

Comment: You’re you’re supposed to be testing continually. Whenever finish processing one file, call MPI_Test repeatedly every few milliseconds until either the test passes (and you can exit), or you get the next file

Comment: That band aid is not good enough, the very same race condition is still there, and you might also end up with some non processed files. Anyway, *"simplicity is the ultimate sophistication"*, so you really should consider something else.

Comment: Hi Gilles, any suggestion on alternative way I can implement this strategy, the rationale behind is I'm trying to distribute the load evenly among the nodes so that only available nodes are pulling work from node 0.
Also, if there are 2 threads in node 1 that perform the communication, will MPI be able to detect which thread is sending the request from node 1 and communicate the information to the correct node?

Comment: My suggestion is already in the comment I appended to your question. What do you mean by thread ? MPI know processes (aka tasks) and they all have a unique rank in the communicator, regardless they are running on the same node or not. If you mean OpenMP or pthread threads, then MPI is unaware of it and you can use tag, `MPI_ANY_TAG` and `MPI_TAG` to figure out which thread from which MPI process sent the message.